# Echo the Result of $test

Tags: variables, echo

```
<?php

$j7=6;
$b=7;

$test= '$j'.$b;

echo $test;

?>
```

How to make the result of echo $test is 6 instead of $j7?

Comment: Check out [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference — What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Comment: still i cant understand all of it sir.if you dont mind,can you explain it to me, sir @SunnyPatel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking to do the following:

```
$test = "${'j'.$b}";
echo $test;      //Outputs 6
```

You're working with [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) which essentially defines a variable based on another variable's contents.